# Aggregate method in Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

I am new to Django and when I use **Aggregate** method, it returns something like:

> {'max__age' : 35}

but I need to display just the number ("35" in this example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use *subscripting* to access the value. So for example:

```
MyModel.objects.aggregate(…)['max__age']
```